# sncredis/bundle key stored in Redis

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I am currently using snc_redis/bundle with predis and was wondering something about the key stored in redis.
Mine looks like per default like this : NnXezxiuBQ

snc_redis:

```
default:
  type: "predis"
  alias: default
  dsn: "%env(REDIS_URL)%"
  options:
    prefix: xxx
```

Given this, it replaces my key per xxxNnXezxiuBQ

Is there a way to define completely the key in the options ?
If not, does this key remain the same given any environment ?
Because I need the full key in order to expire it

Thanks !

Comment: Found a way to bypass the default redis key : 


```$redisKeys = $this->redisClient->keys('*' . $key);

                foreach ($redisKeys as $redisKey) {
                    $this->redisClient->expire($redisKey, 0);
                }
``` 

with the * wildcard, I can get rid of the default key constraint and filter by my own keys